# Some OpenGL features working, some not

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I have been trying to start using OpenGL with C++ on my new arch linux box, but I can only use functions from before OpenGL 3.0.

For example, the following code works:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);  
{  
glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);  
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  
glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);  
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);  
glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);  
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);  
}  
glEnd();
```

but the following does not:

```
GLuint vertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);
```

It cannot find the functions `glGenVertexArrays` and `glBindVertexArray`, as indicated by output from Eclipse: `function glGenVertexArrays cannot be resolved.`

So what would cause this? Bad library linking? Old drivers?

My glxinfo:
`OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6450

OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.12414 Core Profile Context 13.15.100.1 OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30`

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot find the functions `glGenVertexArrays` and `glBindVertexArray`". DO you get linker errors? Or are you missing the function prototypes? Do you use some GL loader like glew?

Comment: what do you use for loading?

Comment: to quote eclipse: "function glGenVertexArrays cannot be resolved"

Comment: @LaszloPapp - I have tried using gl + glut, freeGlut, GLEW, GLFW, same results

Comment: @JaredLoomis: first of all, try to find out what your GL driver actually supports, e.g. with the `glxinfo` utility.

Comment: @derhass - `OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6450  
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.12414 Core Profile Context     13.15.100.1  
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30  
`

Comment: @JaredLoomis: OK, that should do. So there is probably an error on your side. glut/freeglut/glfw all have nothing to do with this (or: not much). How did you try to use glew?

Comment: @derhass - my includes - `#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`

Comment: // Initialize GLEW
 glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
 if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
  return -1;
 }

Comment: @JaredLoomis: And your linker setup? Unresolved symbols are typically a linker issue.

Comment: @derhass - my libraries are: glut, GLU, GL, glfw, glew

Comment: Do you get compiler errors, linker errors, or runtime errors?

Comment: @JaredLoomis: Put this stuff *in your question*, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I am using Arch Linux with an AMD GPU, so there are two drivers: Mesa(Open Source) and Catalyst(Proprietary). I am using catalyst because mesa does not support opengl 3.0+. But I was including GL/gl.h, which is mesa's header file. I fixed this by including GL/glATI.h.

I am not sure if this is a good fix and if it would work on all systems, but it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 2):

It could be bad linking or old drivers, depending on what GPU you have. Are you using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)? You should be linking to that to use those function calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a link-time issue. In OpenGL, GLX/EGL/WGL/... is used to load extensions at run-time (more precisely, to assign procedure addresses). This means that you are not including the proper extension header and/or not linking against the appropriate library and therefore the linker cannot determine the function pointer locations.

In addition, pre-processor definitions may be preventing your extension library (e.g. GLEW) from providing function prototypes and/or symbols for an entire subset of the GL API; you should refer to your library's documentation.

It is still very possible for these functions to be unusable at run-time (e.g. the extension is not implemented), but that will present itself in the form of a NULL pointer rather than a linker error.

Also note that libraries like GLEW need to be updated with each new version of OpenGL. They provide function prototypes, enums, etc. for extensions based on extension specifications. This means that a version of GLEW that was compiled before an extension specification was published will not know anything about that extension :)

You could well be using a version of GLEW that pre-dates OpenGL 3.0, if you did not compile it yourself, or if you did not use a recent code base.

Answer (score 0):

Linking problem happens when you add third party library, such as GL, GLU or GLUT. Its possible the compiler cannot find the .lib file or the .dll files. Some functions such as glbegin() works because maybe they were declared and defined on the header files. glGenVertexArrays is not working because it was only declared on the header file and implemented or defined on a .c or .cpp file. Now if linking is not done you will get error message: func cannot be resolved.